# Issues with characters at the end of an istream

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm writing a parser, and I was previously having trouble when I try to parse identifiers (anything that's valid for a C++ variable name) and unclosed string literals (anything starting with `"`, but missing the closing `"`) at the end of my input. I think it's because the lexer (`TokenStream`) uses `std::noskipws` in these cases and builds the token character by character. Here is where I believe I have narrowed down the problem (shown only for one of the two cases, as the other is very similar logic):

```
std::string TokenStream::get()
{
    char c;
    (*input) >> c; // input is of type istream*

    // other cases...

    if (c == '"')
    {
        std::string s = stringFromChar(c); // just makes a string from the char.
        char d;
        while (true) // 1)
        {
            (*input) >> std::noskipws >> d;
            std::cout << d; // 2)
            if (d == '"')
            {
                s += d;
                (*input) >> std::skipws;
                break; 
            }
            s += d;
        }
        return s;
    }

    // other cases...
}
```

Note that this function is supposed to just generate tokens from the input in a stream-like fashion. Now, if I input either a literal (like `asdf`) or an unclosed string (like `"asdf`), then the program will hang, and the line marked `2)` will just output the last character of the input (in my examples, `f`) over and over again forever.

I've solved this problem by using a check for `input->eof()`, but my question is this:

**Why does the loop (marked `1)` in comments) keep executing when I hit the end of stream, and why does it just print that last character read every time through the loop?**

Comment: Something wrong with checking input for success or doing `std::string s(1, c);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at the loop in question line-by-line

```
    while (true) // 1)
```

That's gonna loop, unless a break is encountered

```
    {
        (*input) >> std::noskipws >> d;
```

Read a character. If can't read character, `d` is likely to be unchanged.

```
        std::cout << d; // 2)
```

Print the character that is just read

```
        if (d == '"')
```

Nope, the last character was not `"` (as specified in the question)

```
        {
            s += d;
            (*input) >> std::skipws;
            break; 
        }
        s += d;
    }
```

Therefore the break is never encountered and the last character is printed in an endless loop.

---

Fix: always use a while look like this for input:

```
char ch;
while (input >> ch) {

    // ch contains a new letter, deal with it

}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. So `(*input) >> d` fails to get anything new (presumably returning false), and `d` hasn't changed, so it's obviously not what we look for to break. Seems like a silly oversight for me, I should have seen that before. Ah well. Much appreciated!

Comment: `(*input) >> d` returns `(*input)`. But yes, as `d` is unchanged it will never break.